# How to make ObjectMapper and JsonSerializer work with generic interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, jackson

The following error occurs during startup of my spring boot application:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JsonSerializer of type com.somepackage.PageJsonSerializer does not define valid handledType() -- must either register with method that takes type argument  or make serializer extend 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer'

How do I get the `ObjectMapper` and `JsonSerializer` to work with a generic interface like `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`?

My JsonSerializer is similar to the one [here](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2018/2018-06-10-pageimpl-json-serialization-with-spring-boot-2/) **but** instead of the class `PageImpl` I am trying to work with the interface `Page`.

```java
public class PageJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Page<?>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Page<?> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        // do some serializing
    }
}
```

I add the serializer to the `ObjectMapper` like this:

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    var pageModule = new SimpleModule();
    pageModule.addSerializer(new PageJsonSerializer());
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModules(pageModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

I have also tried extending `StdSerializer` instead of `JsonSerializer` but I am not sure how to instantiate `StdSerializer` with a generic interface parameter.

I have also tried adding the serializer like this `pageModule.addSerializer(Page.class, new PageJsonSerializer())` which results in a compilation error: `incompatible types: Class<Page> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Page<?>>`.

Comment: .addSerializer(Page.class, new PageJsonSerializer())

Comment: What is the custom serialized supposed to do?

Comment: @VladMamaev your suggestion does not work and gives me the following  compilation error `incompatible types: Class<Page> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Page<?>>`

Comment: @crizzis exactly the same thing what is done here https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2018/2018-06-10-pageimpl-json-serialization-with-spring-boot-2/

Comment: @chriswillow follow the article and remove wildcard <?> from Page<?> value parameter

Comment: @VladMamaev thank you, that worked. the only remaining issue I have is that I now have a warning in my `PageJsonSerializer`: `Raw use of parameterized class 'Page' `. How can avoid the warning without simply suppressing it?

Comment: you _can't_. this _is_ a raw type, it's a recursion: you can't use `Page<?>` and you can't get rid of the warning unless you use `Page<?>`. Simply add `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` and move on.